# How to limit amount of specific symbol in the string when it repeats

Tags: c#, string, text

how to limit amount of specific symbol in the string when it repeats  for example, if I have an input: **"Hello,,,, world....."** to write it into the text document for example, I want to get it as **"hello, world."** remove all extra and keep only one symbol between words. Only for comma and dot, chars can be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var text = "Hello,,,, world.....";

var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(\.|,){2,}", m => m.Value.First().ToString());
```

The regex `@"(\.|,){2,}"` will match `.` or `,` that occurs 2 or more times and replace the matched group for the first character in it.

Comment: ,Hello, it would be good to clarify two things also, first, if I want add some other symbols on this limitation, for example comma, dot and also exclamation mark for example, how to do it? and question two, it works well if I want just  pass it into the file, but  if I want use it directly  in textbox `textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"(\.|,){2,}", m => m.Value.First().ToString());` if I write **hello,,** it throws my carter to beginning of line with extra symbol and I got this **,hello,**

Comment: I can do it this way `@"(\!|:){2,}|(\.|,){2,}"` but it still throws caret to beginning

Answer (score 0):

```
([A-Za-z ]+)([,\.])?([^A-Za-z]+)([A-Za-z ]+)([,\.])?([^A-Za-z]+)
```

This query will match letters, then accept one comma or period, eat the rest, and then repeat.

Comment: Hello, `@"([A-Za-z ]+)([,\.])?([^A-Za-z]+)([A-Za-z ]+)([,\.])?([^A-Za-z]+)"` I don't know maybe I'm doing something wrong, but if I use it this way, it still repeats symbols and then cuts whole string at a certain point and starts it again from the middle